# Is there a way in Snowflake to allow users to get ddl on a procedure but not have USAGE or OWNERSHIP rights on it?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to design my Snowflake DB permissions in a way that allows any user (even read-only users) to discover and understand objects in the database. I have a way of doing this with most objects, but am having trouble with procedures.

It seems that the only privileges on procedures are USAGE and OWNERSHIP. Ideally I could grant another permission like MONITOR so that it would show up in SHOW statements and that would also allow me to GET_DDL().

The only work-around I can see if I want to give read-only people permissions to view the procedure is to make sure all procedures run under the *caller's* permissions and then give them USAGE. That way if there's anything prohibited to them in the procedure they won't be able to actually run it.

Comment: Snowflake finally addressed this, including a workaround for what you described in the last paragraph. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78077841/245915

Answer (score 1):

Change the context of the procedure execution.
By default, the procedure is run in the context of the person creating the procedure and access to its content is restricted.
Replace the context with the caller using the `EXECUTE AS CALLER` clause.
Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_NAME ()
   RETURNS VARCHAR
   LANGUAGE javascript
   EXECUTE AS CALLER
   AS
```

Comment: Hi Michal. Thanks for the suggestion. This is exactly what I suggested in my original question (see the last paragraph). I'd like to not do that, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [information_schema.procedures](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/info-schema/procedures.html).

Example usage: `select * from information_schema.procedures;`.

Comment: This will only show you procedures that you have a permission on.