# Why can't I see all the code from a procedure when using get_ddl or describe?

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is my first posted question here so I hope the format is acceptable.

I am able to execute get_ddl() and DESC PROCEDURE for all of our stored procedures but some have a null `body` when using describe and are cut short when using the get_ddl(). If I connect with the user that is the owner of the SP it does show me the whole procedure. I have also granted all privileges on the procedures to my ETL user in the schema and I still can't see all the code.

This is the result of running get_ddl() on the SP, it is missing the sql command variable and everything after:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_test"()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '';
```

I am able to call the SP with a user that is not the owner and it works correctly. The account admin role was also not able to see the full procedure for all the SP's.

Can someone give me a hand?

Thanks,
James

Comment: I did find that you can do a get_ddl() on the schema and it gives you the create statements for all the objects (Tables, procedures...) as another work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake finally explained the issue earlier this year: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/GET-DDL-funtion-returns-only-the-Sored-Procedure-definition

> This is part of the design of the Owner's Right Stored Procedure.

If you are OK with less-privileged users calling the procedure, you can change it to Caller's Right. Then anyone who has usage permission for the procedure will be able to see the full body content.

If you want to keep it restricted to Owner's Right to run it, you will have to write a wrapper procedure. Instructions and example are given in the article.

Answer (score 2):

This may be because Snowflake supports SP overloading. What you may be seeing is an early copy of the SP before it had the variables added. It may have been added accidentally without any contents. For example:

```
-- Someone creates the shell of an SP like this:
create or replace procedure foo()
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
$$;

-- Later someone adds one or more variables and a body
create or replace procedure foo(MY_VARIABLE string)
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
    return "Hello world.";
$$;

-- Get the old signature, body is empty
select get_ddl('procedure', 'foo()');
describe procedure foo();

-- Get the newer signature, body has contents
select get_ddl('procedure', 'foo(string)');
describe procedure foo(string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Interesting point Greg. From what I can tell, there is only one SP with the same name for the SP I care about monitoring in this schema. It has no variables needed. It might be overloaded on another schema but seems unlikely since GET_DDL() requires the dw, schema and variables when ran.

Comment: Just a thought: do the SPs, that you can't see the body of, reference any objects that the user doesn't have permissions on?

Answer (score 2):

I've got this issue too, and after search I found its a permission problem.
in snowflake `USAGE` permission does not enable read procedure body, only the definition of name and parameters. so grant read permission to your user and you will see the content in `GET_DDL()` command, `DESC` procedure, `SHOW` procedure, etc.
you can see your permission using `SHOW GRANT TO USER USER_NAME` or `SHOW GRANT TO ROLE ROLE_NAME`.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it? Getting a read_only role to see the body of the procedure.